# How to generate random numbers with given length of input to add and multiply

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to generate 2 lists of random numbers between 1 to 10 and trying to do an user input for how many numbers they want to generate per list. Then I'm trying to figure out how to add and multiply the 2 lists together.

The problem is that I feel like I know how to make all this happen separately but I can't seem to figure out how to put them together using main()

for example : i import random then create a blank list for the random generator to put numbers into the empty list, but I don't know how to create an easy way for the user input the number in for the length of the list.

```
import random

myList = []

for i in range(1,11):
    x = random.randint(1, 10)
    myList.append(x)


print(myList)

input("Amount of numbers preferred in a list: ")   <---- not sure where to put this and add more code to be part of the generating process.
```

Answer (score 0):

in order for you to generate two lists of length the user decides:

```
from random import randint
list1 = []
list2 = []
len1 = int(input("What is the length of list1? :"))
len2 = int(input("What is the length of list2? :"))
for _ in range(len1):
    list1.append(randint(1,10))
for _ in range(len2):
    list2.append(randint(1,10))
print(list1)
print(list2)
```

Comment: Thank you, do you have any books or videos to recommend python for beginners that are actually useful? it seems that my book doesn't go too into details about the things that happen between the lines. It seems to only show main ideas. Or all books like this?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) `randint()` bounds are both inclusive so you should use: `randint(1,10)` if `x in [1,10]`

Comment: @Suii this is a book where i learned absolute basics called [learn python in one day and learn it well](https://www.amazon.com/Python-Beginners-Hands-Project-Project-ebook/dp/B00R9JPDN4) but based on what you said about more in-depth knowledge of python, 1.) I learned a lot from watching the lectures of an online college course like [this one](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-using-python-2) and 2.) just coding! You would be surprised at how much you learn. ALSO i am not very professional. in fact i just learned coding for fun and i am in high school.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the input, convert it to int, and use list comprehension to generate the lists:

```py
import random

x  = int(input("Amount of numbers preferred in a list: "))
l1 = [random.randint(1, 10) for i in range(x)]
```

You can do the same for list2. Be careful of which bounds of `randint()` that are inclusive and which is exclusive. For that, look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)